# About questions that seem stupid

Tags: support

I personally don't believe that there is a stupid question. I have a question that related to judgment about questions (and also answers).

I asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266913/do-we-not-need-a-zeroth-law-of-motion-similar-to-the-zeroth-law-of-thermodynamic) question today.

I think (completely believe) if my reputation was 200000, then **all** (99.999999 %) people were saying "*Oh! What a nice question!*"

But they offence and ridicule me because my reputation is very low.

I think (completely believe) if I was writing in my profile that "*I am a post doctor of physics, I am full professor of physics, I have Gauss' chair at the moment, etc.*" then **all** (99.999999 %) people were saying "*Oh! What a nice question!*"

But they offence and ridicule me because I am just a nothing.

I think (completely believe) if I had answered some questions about quantum mechanic or relativity before then **all** (99.999999 %) people were saying "*Oh! What a nice question!*"

But they offence and ridicule me because I just know a little bit about laws of Newton and a little bit about thermodynamics laws.

The above argument is valid about answers too.

My question is:

Why?

Comment: Why what? Are you asking why people offend and ridicule you? If so, could you include some examples of this ridicule? I looked at your question and I'm not seeing any such responses. Are you asking why your question was not well received? Or something else?

Comment: @DavidZ Thank you because of your attention! If you cannot see ridicule, this is because you don't want to see.

Comment: To be honest, I completely disagree with your assessment on voting patterns - but I'd be happy to be proven wrong by examples. Voting patterns are relatively easy to explore on the [data.se]; data in comments is somewhat harder to mine. Can you point to posts that you consider equivalent where the response was different and that you attribute to the poster's rep? Pointing fingers is easy - but if you want change, show (don't tell) what's wrong.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you very much for your attention and time! I cannot give examples because this is a relative thing and not mathematics. I never can **prove** what I am saying. I just hope to readers' justice. All of us know what I am saying, but some people (like david z) never satisfy because they don't want to accept the truth. Because truth is in contrast with which they want and do. He is a moderator but he always take personally. Most of his downvotes and close votes aren't based on logic and science.

Comment: Sure, that's the easy way out, and you're welcome to take it. If you want to change people's opinions, though, it's going to take more than that. So what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I can achieve nothing here unless some kind and fair **high rep** users or some users with high scientific degree support me. They can answer my [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266913/do-we-not-need-a-zeroth-law-of-motion-similar-to-the-zeroth-law-of-thermodynamic) and prove that **all** people like david z are mistaken. In addition, I think david z doesn't deserve to be a moderator and I will be happy if I can change even one opinion with respect to him. One thing else, do you know who is the owner of the SE?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have asked a pretty basic question about notation, and you have received two pretty thoughtful answers; the only negative response that question is the voting, which I feel is commensurate with the question. High-rep users [do have low-score posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/509329/) (and that doesn't include deleted posts). To be honest with you, this post feels to me like pure whining: you feel there's a problem, you complain that others don't understand you, but you're not prepared to put in any work to convince anyone. Why should anyone listen?

Comment: That's a lot of very strong words based on absolutely zero evidence. Seriously. David Z interacted with you *once* (providing a helpful comment, at that). This is where you do *need* to either provide very clear examples of the abuse of authority, or explicitly back off from the claim. If you want to use strong (f) words, you also cannot hide behind an 'et al.'. Who is doing this, and what posts are you referring to? You are at a point where you need to back up your accusations with evidence or stand them down.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sorry sir I wouldn't like to continue this discussion. I will wait and hope to the future. I am sure that there are plenty people like me. I am the worst option to discussion because my English is so terrible and when I want to type "How are you?" I have to look to three dictionary 6 times and finally I will write wrong sentence. So, I hope that some one comes and continues this discussion with you. At the end, I have an advice  for you: *"Don't support david z, he is a very harmful person"*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for this meta site because it does not provide any evidence for its claims against other users, nor does it show any evidence that there is a problem. I also agree with you that there's little point in continuing this discussion until any of your claims are backed up.

Comment: Leaving aside that you have no way to know what the votes of the users here are based on since they are anonymous, there is no requirement for votes to be based on "logic and science" - what does that even *mean*? Votes are expressions of opinions and people have rather clearly  expressed their opinion that your question is bad in this case. Live with it. Slinging around baseless accusations will not achieve anything - stop visiting this site if you are unable to cope with its basic functionality like users' ability to vote as they see fit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is.

Comment: It's a bummer but there are quite a few trolls here.....some people are more imterested im belittling others than helping othera.  It's beat to try and ignore them.  Some peoplw dont know what the voting button is for....

Comment: Lucas, I commented on your question, which had received 9 down-votes.  I asked (humorously) if your true purpose in posting was to get a Gold Badge for a question with 25 down-votes.  You decided this was ridicule, but I did not intend it to be.  DavidZ (I think) promptly deleted my comment, which was not pertinent.  As in a few of your previous comments to me, you have presumed ill-will where none was intended.  You take disagreement and criticism too personally.

Comment: ... I considered your question to have been posted simply to provoke a discussion (so it should have been in the ChatRoom).  And that is what it did.  In the end it clawed back to -6, and if left open might have reached 0 eventually.  What I did not like about your question is that it showed no effort : You did not give any reasons why a Zeroth Law of Mechanics is needed or make any proposal what it should be.  You left it entirely to others to interpret your question and propose solutions.  I down-voted for that reason.  I do the same to all similar questions, it was not personal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I haven't voted or commented in any of your posts.

I think that the main issue is your attitude. Watching your profile, you have 109 posts, and only two of them have a negative score. I don't think that you have any reason to claim that you are a victim of ridicule or fraudulent voting patterns.

Yes, your last question has received a lot of downvotes. You're trying to modify Newton Laws, just for the sake of it, without even proposing a justification. "Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence", and you have provided none. It's normal that lots of people agree that your question is bad.

**But they are just judging your question, they aren't judging *you*.** Don't take it as a personal affront, because it isn't. Take it as a chance to improve your question and learn something from the comments and votes.

My advice: try to calm yourself and don't visit the page in a couple of days. When you come back, please read some of your comments like these:

[image]
[image]

I guess that you will realize that your attitude was not adequate, and you will do the correct thing as you did here:

[image]

Please understand that I'm trying to help you, that my intention is not to offend you.

Comment: Thank you very much because of your attention and time! Thank you because of your goodwill! As I said to Emilio Pisanty, my poor English doesn't let me to discuss well and so I don't want to discuss anymore. But, none of you (you and Emilio Pisanty) know what events have been happened in the past (between me and some users). Regardless of those events, your answer is perfectly good and useful. I got happy so much when I saw that you don't support anyone. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

> I think (completely believe) if my reputation was 200000, then all
>   (99.999999 %) people were saying "Oh! What a nice question!"

It is remarkable though, to be honest, not unexpected, that your post is all about how you believe participants here "offence and ridicule" *you* - and yet you're evidently profoundly *oblivious* to just how insulting the remark above is likely be to those that regularly participate here.

You've essentially painted *all* that participate here as shallow human beings that look at one's reputation points as a measure of the quality of a question.

The blatant contradiction is this:  if you "completely believe" this, *why on Earth are you interested in answers from such human beings?*

I'm voting to close your question but honestly, I *completely believe* that you should consider deleting it.

Comment: Thank you for your time! You are *completely* right sir. But let's sit and wait for future. I think future will be better than now, although I have no hope. Because to being better, future need better people. To have better people, they need better **teachers**. We are their teachers and if you are fair you should confirm that none of us aren't good teachers. But I prefer future's teachers mostly are similar to me than you. Have a good time sir!