# Why don't close-vote counts agree with the number of close votes on review pages?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, review

The process of closure of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267302/about-time-and-time-dilation) of mine has been started. As you can see in the figure below, the number of close votes is 3. (the picture has been taken at 18, July, 2016, 06:00 UTC)
[image]

But there are just two close votes in the [review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/138278) page of that question. (the picture has been taken at 18, July, 2016, 06:00 UTC)
[image]

How is it possible?

---

## Addition:

As you can see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/137518), the same question of mine has been reviewed once before this time. I wonder how dose the closure process start by a "Leave open" vote? (the picture has been taken at 18, July, 2016, 06:30 UTC)
[image]

---

## Addition:

As you can see [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8896/about-questions-that-seem-stupid), this question of mine has been closed by five votes. But there is just one close vote in the [review](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/214) page. (the picture has been taken at 18, July, 2016, 06:45 UTC)
[image]

Comment: The information who voted how is public, there is no need to blacken the names of the users involved.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well! You are right. It was just a personal preference of mine not a legal requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Review pages only show close votes cast as part of the review process, and they do not show any votes cast independently, i.e. directly on the question page.

Typically, questions are put on the queue by a direct vote to close, so there is usually one more close vote than there are reviews. If more people vote independently of the queue, this difference can increase.

(On the other hand, some questions end up on the queue through a flag as off-topic by a <3k user, in which case all the votes could come from review. I don't know how often this happens, though.)